# How to Integrate Laravel API and Next.js Frontend on One Website

Tags: laravel, next.js

I'm using Laravel to build the API, and Next.js as the frontend. The API is being developed by person A, and the frontend (Next.js) is being developed by person B. Please guide me on how to merge these two files to run on one website.

Comment: Use Sanctum, https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#api-token-authentication

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly simple noting too difficult

First you need to configure the Laravel API routes to prefix with `/api`. For example:

```
Route::prefix('api')->group(function() {
  Route::apiResource('posts', PostController::class);
});
```

Then set up the Next.js app. Make sure to configure `next.config.js` for API routing:

```js
module.exports = {
  basePath: '/next',
  reactStrictMode: true,

  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/api/:path*',
        destination: '/api/:path*'  
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Next, Next.js pages (did you see what I did there) make API requests to `/api` endpoint. For example:

```js
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = await fetch('/api/posts');
  const posts = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      posts
    }
  }
}
```

Then what you have to do is deploy Laravel and Next.js apps separately - Laravel to root, Next.js to `/next`

Now configure web server to serve Laravel's `public` at root, and Next.js `build` output at `/next`

Set CORS headers in Laravel to allow requests from Next.js

Finally configure API authentication and you are on your own

Okay so you should be all set now (make sure to properly prefix Laravel routes, configure Next.js routing, and deploy them to different paths on the same domain) that's the crux of it